# DOM not updating in vue.js even when data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The changes are not reflected in DOM, even when the data is changing properly. Here is a very basic example to demonstrate the issue -

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="username" />
  <p>{{error}}</p>
  <button @click="saveData">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      model.error = ''; // adding a new property
      return model; // 'model' is a global variable
    }
    methods: {
      saveData() {
        if (!this.username) {
          this.error = 'Please enter the username!';
          return;
        }
        // ... other code
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

After calling `saveData()` the `error` variable contains the message if username is not filled. But it's not showing up in the paragraph.

There is a trick. If I also change the `username` property when the `error` variable is changed, the changes are reflected.

Comment: The object returned from `data` is used directly to create the `$data` for the component. If you use the same `model` object in multiple components they will all end up sharing the same `$data` object. That includes the `error` property. Is that really what you want? If it is then just add an `error` property to the initial definition of `model` so that the property is made reactive when Vue first encounters that object.

Comment: I want to add ```error``` property only to this component. Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return error or Vue doesn't have access to it.

```
data () {
  return {
    error: '',
    model: model,
  };
}
```

Comment: I will have to add model keyword while accessing each property. I tried adding error variable in model & then returning the model, but still didn't work.

Comment: I updated the question... and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve what you're trying to do, as long as `error` and `username` properties are defined on `model` for `data`. I've included a simple snippet below, showing it working. Take a look at [Declaring Reactive Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) in the documentation.

```js
var model = {
  username: "Default"
};


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    model.error = model.error || "";
    return model;
  },
  methods: {
    updateError() {
      this.error = "Test";
    },
    updateUsername() {
      this.username = "Hello, World!";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="updateError">Update Error</button>
  <button type="button" @click="updateUsername">Update Username</button>
  <div>Error: {{error}}</div>
  <div>UserName: {{username}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that problem is with ```model``` object. If I try any other object, it works!